# How to get only filenames within a directory using c#?

Tags: c#, .net

When I use the line of code as below , I get an string array containing the entire path of the individual files .

```
private string[] pdfFiles = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Documents", "*.pdf");
```

I would like to know if there is a way to only retrieve the file names in the strings rather than the entire paths.

Answer (score 171, accepted):

You can use [`Path.GetFileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) to get the filename from the full path

```
private string[] pdfFiles = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Documents", "*.pdf")
                                     .Select(Path.GetFileName)
                                     .ToArray();
```

---

EDIT: the solution above uses [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linq), so it requires .NET 3.5 at least. Here's a solution that works on earlier versions:

```
private string[] pdfFiles = GetFileNames("C:\\Documents", "*.pdf");

private static string[] GetFileNames(string path, string filter)
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, filter);
    for(int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
        files[i] = Path.GetFileName(files[i]);
    return files;
}
```

Comment: Hi Thomas , I get an error like this   'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Is there anything else that I need to consider ?

Comment: Add `using System.Linq;` at the beginning of the file, and a reference to the `System.Core` assembly if it's not already there. It requires .NET 3.5 or higher, I'll post a solution for .NET 2.0 if you need it

Comment: My target is wince7, so the  solution for earlier than .NET 3.5 was useful.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the method `Path.GetFileName(yourFileName);` [(MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) to just get the name of the file.

Comment: The question is about a collection of items, not single string value treatment.

Answer (score 8):

You could use the DirectoryInfo and FileInfo classes.

```
//GetFiles on DirectoryInfo returns a FileInfo object.
var pdfFiles = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\Documents").GetFiles("*.pdf");

//FileInfo has a Name property that only contains the filename part.
var firstPdfFilename = pdfFiles[0].Name;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath);

foreach (var file_name in fileEntries){
    string fileName = file_name.Substring(directoryPath.Length + 1);
    Console.WriteLine(fileName);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an explanation of your answer?  Can you explain how your solution is substantially different from Thomas Levesque's 8-year-standing answer?  And, in particular, can you explain why you use `Substring` rather than making use of the `Path` function that will do the same, in a potentially more robust way?

Answer (score 1):

There are so many ways :)

1st Way:

```
string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(path, "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(folders);
```

2nd Way:

```
string[] folders = new DirectoryInfo(yourPath).GetDirectories().Select(d => d.Name).ToArray();
```

3rd Way:

```
string[] folders = 
    new DirectoryInfo(yourPath).GetDirectories().Select(delegate(DirectoryInfo di)
    {
        return di.Name;
    }).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use linq

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(LoanFolder).Select(file => Path.GetFileName(file));
```

Note: EnumeratesFiles is more efficient compared to Directory.GetFiles as you can start enumerating the collection of names before the whole collection is returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GetNameOfFiles
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           string[] fileArray = Directory.GetFiles(@"YOUR PATH");
           for (int i = 0; i < fileArray.Length; i++)
           {

               Console.WriteLine(fileArray[i]);
           }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```