# Sort list items [full path] by file name in C#

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I have a list of type string. Each string is a full path to a file. Now I would like to sort this list by the name of the file.

When I use the Sort() method, the list would be sorted by the full path. But the path can be different.

Is there a simple way to sort the list by whats left after the last \ of each item?

Comment: sort on `Path.GetFilename("full_path")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get only filenames within a directory using c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7140081/how-to-get-only-filenames-within-a-directory-using-c)

Comment: @PeterB That question is unrelated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`System.IO.Path.GetFileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx) and LINQ:

```
files = files.OrderBy(System.IO.Path.GetFileName).ToList();
```

If you want to compare in a case-insensitive manner you can pass a `StringComparer`:

```
files = files.OrderBy(System.IO.Path.GetFileName, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase).ToList();
```

Note that `OrderBy` (and `OrderByDescending`) uses a stable sort algorithm as opposed to [`List.Sort`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s(v=vs.110).aspx). That means that all elements which are equal stay in the original order.

Comment: Also it is likely that the list of files can be obtained from `Directory.EnumerateFiles()` which can be used with `OrderBy` - in which case this saves temporarily storing the files in a list or array before sorting them.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for `Path.GetFileName`:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx

```
   List<string> files = ...

   // when sorting via Sort we should compare file names
   files.Sort((left, right) => 
     string.Compare(Path.GetFileName(left), Path.GetFileName(right)));
```

The advantages of `Sort` over Linq `OrderBy` are

- `Sort` performs *in place* sorting when Linq creates an additional collection via `.ToList()`
- You can put a complex sorting algorithm just within the lambda function; in case of Linq one has to implement `IComparer<T>` interface

The disadvantages are

- Linq wants just `IEnumerable<T>` when `Sort` requires `List<T>`.
- `Sort()` uses *unstable* sorting algorithms (if two items considered being equal their actual order in the sorted list is not guaranteed)
- current simplest implementtation `string.Compare(Path.GetFileName(left), Path.GetFileName(right))` calls `Path.GetFileName` *too often* (about twice as many as `OrderBy`)

Comment: This attempt works better than the others since you can explicitly specify the CultureInfo and CompareOptions, e.g. `String.Compare(Path.GetFileName(left), Path.GetFileName(right), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, CompareOptions.Ordinal)`

Comment: @Manfred Radlwimmer: another advantage is that `Sort` sorts the list *in place* unlike Linq which creates an additional collection

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer: you can use the overload of `OrderBy` to pass a `StringComparer`. I've edited [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40759683/284240) accordingly.

Comment: A major disadvantage of this over using `OrderBy()` is that `Path.GetFileName()` will be called twice for each comparison, while `OrderBy` only calls it once for each item in the list. The number of comparisons can greatly outnumber the number of items in the list.

Comment: Another disadvantage is that `List.Sort` performs an unstable whereas `Enumerable.OrderBy` a stable sort. So equal items remain in their original order.

Answer (score 1):

this example code,

```
 var getFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName("C:\temp\name.txt"); > temp.txt

 var getfileNameWithoutExtention = System.IO.Path.GetFileName("C:\temp\name.txt"); > name

 var getextention = System.IO.Path.GetFileName("C:\temp\name.txt"); > .txt



 List<string> patsh = new List<string>
        {
            @"C:\temp\name.txt",
            @"C:\music\ranbow.mp3",
            @"C:\net\core.cs",
            @"C:\java\fr.jar"
        };



 patsh = patsh.OrderBy(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension).ToList();
```

if you want to do it with file extension

```
 patsh = patsh.OrderBy(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension).ThenBy(System.IO.Path.GetExtension).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick for you

```
List<string> fullfilepath = new List<string>() { "C:\\text1.txt", "C:\\text2.txt", "D:\\text4.txt", "C:\\text3.txt", "C:\\text6.txt", "D:\\text5.txt" };
List<string> sortedfilename = fullfilepath.OrderBy(x => Path.GetFileName(x)).ToList();
```

Comment: How is this different from Tim's answer?

Answer (score -1):

You can also sort it by fileName like this:

```
fileName = path.Split('\').Last();
```

Comment: It's a backslash, not a slash

Comment: Backslashes need to be escaped. [I'm getting a deja-vu here ^^](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMRPA.jpg)